# Move last part of a file name to the begin

Tags: bash, file-rename, mv

I would like to modify the name of several files in a folder. The name are in this format:

```
Name_name_name_name_XXXX.fa
```

I would like:

```
XXXX_Name_name_name_name.fa
```

I tired using

```
for f in *.fa; do mv "${f/.fa/Name_name_name_name.fa}";done

output Name_name_name_name_XXXX_Name_name_name_name.fa
```

and then

```
for f in *.fa; do mv "${f/Name_name_name_name_//}"; done
```

to remove the 4 name_name. but it didnt work.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
for f in *.fa; do
   mv "$f" $(sed -E 's/^(.+)_([^.]+)\./\2_\1./' <<< "$f")
done
```

`sed` command uses 2 capture groups. 1st group contains string before last underscore and 2nd group contains `XXXX` part (part between last _` and dot).

Answer (score 1):

Try this using perl's [rename](/questions/tagged/rename) in just one command using regex *capture groups*:

```
rename -n 's/(.*?)_([^_]+)\.fa$/$2_$1/' *.fa
```

(remove -n switch when your tests are OK)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result like

```
.../rename: Perl script, ASCII text executable
```

and not containing:

```
ELF
```

then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

(replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl's rename` command.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL)

---

Last but not least, this tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.

Comment: Thanks I will try with rename too